# Blank page beyond dashboard

Tags: admin

[image]

Our page is not showing anything past the dashboard. All that is showing is on the Jetpack section and the Portfolio section.

Has anyone got any ideas why this is happening? Is it because we haven't been updating the site?

We're a bunch of computer illiterate people here.. so any non-technical or low-technical advice would be appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Something is breaking the back-end. Set debug to true in wp-config.php and see what errors do you get.

Answer (score 0):

If the front-end of the website is still working correctly then it will likely be that your PHP memory is being exhausted due to either too many plugins and/or some plugins using too much of your PHP resources.

The links in this thread should be your next port of call: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/after-log-in-screen-goes-blank